# Analog EXPLAIN MySql for elasticsearch

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

Does anybody knows functionality like `EXPLAIN` for elasticsearch.

We have a lot of data (for one month - 40M items) and time of response (across several months) is not very quick - around 30-50 seconds

It will be good use some functionality like `EXPLAIN` for improving performance of queries. (we have different queries - with and without aggregation and all queries, which use indexes with lot of items are slow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Version 2.2 they added the profile api:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/search-profile.html

It's not possible before that. The only other thing you could do is to check the node performances via cat-api (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/cat-nodes.html)

Comment: Thank you, we need to update our elasticsearch, because we use 1.5 version

Comment: @yAnTar Updating is probably a good idea anyway, since the performance should increase already by that. But be careful, version 2 introduced quite some breaking changes. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-2.0.html